# Get image in storage in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel-5

I have an image in `storage->app->upload->images->1472803410756.jpg`. When I type url `http://localhost:8012/demo/storage/app/upload/images/1472803410756.jpg`, browser show my image exactly. But run with `php artisan serve`, url: `http://localhost:8000/storage/app/upload/images/1472803410756.jpg` browser not found my image. How can fix it?

**My html code:**

```
<td><img class="table_image"  src="{{asset("storage/app/upload/images/$product->product_image")}}"></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong way you get the image from storage folder.Because storage folder having only write permissions. So, Firstly you need to create the route of storage path

```
enter code here
Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
    $path = storage_path('app/upload/images/' . $filename);

    if (!File::exists($path)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
    return $response;
});
```

After that your img tag look like this:-

```
<td><img class="table_image"  src="{{url("storage/".$product->product_image)}}"></td>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: glad to help! not forget to accept the right answer (y)